# Unable to fetch the option chain data from the latest NSE website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using python 3.7 for this task.

Solutions tried:

- I have tried using selenium but the data does not load on the webpage.
- I tried using requests as well but there is no such URL which gives me proper data. The JSON data that can be fetched will give improper result because there is no way to set the expiry date.
- And I cannot use already available libraries as they are fetching data from the old website.

Link to the option chain page on NSE website:

- Old website: https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17
- New website: https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain

Comment: You should try fetching the base URL from the NSE site. Try Inspecting the page, there under Network tab you will be able to find the underlying URL.
After looking into it. Here is the URL that you need --> https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY

Comment: I have tried it but it gives an improper data as there is no way to set the expiry date.

Comment: Try this code, You will have to add libraries and header section:
`expiry_dt = '24-Sep-2020';` `url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY';` `data = requests.get(url, headers=header).content;` `data2 = data.decode('utf-8');` `df = json.loads(data2);` `json_ce = [data['CE'] for data in df['records']['data'] if "CE" in data and data['expiryDate'] == expiry_dt];` `df_ce = pd.json_normalize(json_ce);`

Comment: this should be as answer. also i haven't seen python with semi colons ;   ;)

Comment: **Check this link for the solution** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757973/how-do-i-get-the-live-option-chain-using-python/65804899#65804899)